# Prove there is no strictly increasing function $f$ from rationals to reals

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Prove that there is no strictly increasing function $f: Q \rightarrow R$ such that $f(Q)=R$. You may not use cardinality.

Where I am: Since $f$ is strictly increasing, $f$ has an inverse (I will denote $f^{-1}$ by $g$). I know $g(R)=Q$. I know how to get a contradiction using $g$ by using the Intermediate Value Theorem. However, I need to have $g$ be continuous in order to apply the IVT. I do know that g is also strictly increasing and 1 to 1. I just need help on showing $g$ is continuous, and I can take it from there.

Update: Using the solution provided by T.A.E., I think I may have come up with something. Please give me feedback on this new attempt. I will be using the sequence definition of continuity as well.

Suppose such an $f$ exists. Since $f(Q)$ is an interval and $f$ is strictly increasing, $f$ is continuous (by a Theorem we were taught). Let $\{l_n\}$ in Q be such that $\{l_n\}$ is strictly increasing and converges to $\sqrt{2}$. Then $\{f(l_n)\}$ is an increasing sequence that is bounded above by some real number. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem,  $\{f(l_n)\}$ converges to some $L$. There is a $q$ in $Q$ such that $f(q)=L$ by the definition of $f$. But this contradicts the continuity of $f$ because $\{l_n\}$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$ which is irrational so $\sqrt{2}$ is not equal to $q$.

Comment: You can't have $g$ be continuous, because there is no $x$ for which $g(x)=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: You have an injection $g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$, right ? This would imply that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, isn't it ?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui:  True, but we can't use cardinality.

Comment: @RossMillikan, do you have another suggestion then? My professor suggested using f inverse, although he didn't suggest going after the continuity of f inverse

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: We aren't assuming f is continuous, but it is continuous implicitly because f is strictly increasing and its image is an interval (this is by a theorem I am allowed to use). So the problem doesn't say it explicitly but yeah, it is.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737012/prove-there-is-no-strictly-increasing-function-f-from-irrationals-to-reals

Comment: Then you are there.  $f$ continuous implies $g$ continuous, then IVT says there must be $\sqrt 2$ in the range of $g$, contradiction

Comment: @GabrielR. I actually did got to that thread, but it isn't the same question. I cannot use the first solution because 0 is a rational number. The last two responses on that thread were unclear and incomplete to me.

Comment: @Ankur can't you just adapt the proof with $\sqrt(2)$ instead ? the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected but $\mathbb{R}$ is not, remains true

Comment: @RossMillikan. Is there any way to formally prove that f continuous implies its inverse continuous? My teacher said that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui, are you referring to my proof or another one?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui sorry, I just saw what you were referring to, my bad!

Comment: If $f$ is a strictly increasing bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$, then he inverse of $f$ is a strictly increasing bijection $g$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$. If $g$ is continuous, you get a contradiction using the intermediate value theorem. If $g$ is not continuous, well, a monotonic function can have only jump discontinuities; there should be some way to get a contradiction from that.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is such a function $f$. I'll show that this leads to a contradiction.

Let $\{ l_{n}\}$ be an increasing sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt{2}$, and let $\{ r_{n}\}$ be a decreasing sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt{2}$. Then $\{f(l_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded above and, so, converges to some $L$. Similarly $\{f(r_{n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to some $R$. Furthermore, $L=R$ because, if not, $f$ cannot assume any value in $(L,R)$. By assumption, there is some rational $q$ such that $f(q)=L=R$. However, $l_{n} < q < r_{n}$ must hold because $f(l_{n}) < f(q) < f(r_{n})$ and because $f$ is strictly increasing. But there is no rational $q$ such that $l_{n} < q < r_{n}$ for all $n$. This contradiction proves the result.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was just wondering if the following modification would work. Since f is strictly increasing and its image is an interval, f is continuous. Therefore, once I've proved that {f(l_n)} converges to L and {f(r_n)} converges to R, can I invoke continuity to establish that L=R?

Comment: The argument I gave you shows that you can extend $f$ continuously to $\mathbb{R}$ because of how the range cannot have interval gaps $(L,R)$. So there are several ways to tackle this problem.

Comment: Awesome, thank you again. I put my own proof above if you don't mind giving me feedback.

Comment: You should tackle this the way that makes sense to you. There are a lot of inter-connected properties of the real numbers at work in this problem.

Comment: This argument might be easier to phrase via Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you very much, I'll be sure to take your solution into account.